# Thread safe Singleton: why the memory model does not guarantee that the new instance will be seen by other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have read in Jon's Skeet online page about how to create a thread safe Singleton in C#

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

```
// Bad code! Do not use!
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance=null;

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

in the paragraph below this code it says:

> As hinted at before, the above is not thread-safe. Two different
>   threads could both have evaluated the test if (instance==null) and
>   found it to be true, then both create instances, which violates the
>   singleton pattern. Note that in fact the instance may already have
>   been created before the expression is evaluated, but the memory model
>   doesn't guarantee that the new value of instance will be seen by other
>   threads unless suitable memory barriers have been passed.

Can you please explain why doesn't the memory model does not guarantee that the new value of instance will be seen by other threads?

the static variable is located on the heap, but why it is not shared with other threads immediately? do we need to wait for the context switch so the other thread will know the instance is not null anymore?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks for the edit

Comment: It is just the way the processor works.  Your machine has one with more than one execution core, so can execute more than one thread at the same time.  Nice.  But that does mean that both threads can execute that code at the exact same time so will both see the variable set to null.  Not the only problem, they also have a cached copy of the memory content.  So an update in one is not immediately visible in another.  Which does mean that the threads don't even have to be executing this code at the exact same spot.  This is why locking is important.  Use `Lazy<T>` please.

Comment: @HansPassant great answer. this is what I am looking for, how does the context switch play it's part in this scenario? why do we need the lock or Lazy<T> here? how can we get the miss in the Heap?

Comment: The question is vague -- "why not?" questions are usually too vague to answer. Are you asking "what guarantees are made by the memory model, and how is this situation require guarantees that are not made?" Are you asking "why was the memory model not designed the way I think a memory model should be designed?" Are you asking "what practical considerations in chip design can cause problems with this code?" Don't ask "why not" questions; ask *what* and *how* questions.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks I will edit my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can you please explain why doesn't the memory model does not guarantee that the new value of instance will be seen by other threads?

The memory model is complex and not terribly clearly documented at the moment, but fundamentally there are very few situations where it's safe to rely on a value that's written by one thread being "seen" on another thread without either some locking or other inter-thread communication going on.

For example, consider this:

```
// Bad code, do not use
public class BigLoop
{
    private static bool keepRunning = true;

    public void TightLoop()
    {
        while (keepRunning)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        keepRunning = false;
    }
}
```

If you created two threads, one of which calls `TightLoop` and another of which calls `Stop`, there's no guarantee that the looping method will *ever* terminate.

There are lots of levels of caching in modern CPUs, and requiring that *every* read goes back to main memory would remove a lot of optimizations. So we have memory models which make guarantees about which changes will *definitely* be visible in what situations. Other than those guarantees, the JIT compiler is allowed to assume that there's effectively only a single thread - so it could cache the value of the field in a register, and never hit main memory again, for example.

The currently-documented memory model is woefully inadequate, and would *suggest* that some clearly-weird optimizations should be valid. I wouldn't go *too* far down that route, but it's worth reading Joe Duffy's blog post on the [CLR 2.0 memory model](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/10/clr-20-memory-model/). (That's stronger than the documented ECMA memory model, but a blog post isn't the ideal place for such a key piece of documentation, and I think more clarity is still needed.)

> The static variable is located on the heap, but why it is not shared with other threads?

It *is* shared with other threads - but the value won't necessarily immediately be visible.

Comment: but the value won't necessarily immediately be visible? because we are waiting for the context switch to happen?

Comment: @Gilad: Because of *many* potential reasons. Maybe the JIT compiler inserted a read earlier and cached the value in a register or on the stack. Maybe it's due to CPUs. Maybe you're actually executing on a runtime where everything is made of multiple computers networked together, and they only transport data when they absolutely have to. I'm afraid the memory model is a really complex area.

Comment: @Gilad no it wont. We trade always immediate visibility to improve performance of the code on the compiler, JITer, and processor level. But they put tools in place like Memory Barriers and locks to disable those performance improvements to get around potential bugs like Jon mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Gilad: Don't think about processors and memory busses and context switches and all that.  Those are implementation details subject to change. The fundamental problem is that C# makes certain promises about how reads and writes will be observed to be ordered with respect to special events like threads starting and locks being taken. Those promises do NOT include a promise that two threads will observe a consistent ordering of reads and writes *unless forced to by a guarantee of the memory model*.

Comment: @EricLippert cool thanks! I like this approach. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

> Can you please explain why doesn't the memory model does not guarantee that the new value of instance will be seen by other threads?

There are a few problems with that code. Because there isn't a new value assigned to the variable just yet. There are quite some things that can happen between comparing for null (`if (instance==null)`) and the assignment of the new value (`instance = new Singleton();`).

The problem you reference is about memory that is cached by the processor, the variable is still `null` there, but already set in memory by the assignment from the code. It will update that cached memory later on.

Comment: The page is hinting at rather more than that. The instance *may* already have been created, but without the reference being visible to the other thread.

Comment: I understand, but then I have to replicate the entire article here. You can do that much better than I can. I just wanted to outline one possibility. @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet By that, do you mean that a second thread could check `instance==null` between the constructor call and the setting of the class field?

Comment: @DStanley: I'm saying that a second thread could check `instance == null` *after* the first thread has assigned to `instance`, but still read a value of `null`, because memory models are hard.

Comment: @JonSkeet And I understand that problem, I have read articles from you and Eric, but I don't think it is necessary to outline all reasons that code could fail here. Do you?

Comment: I am a little confused with the heap static variable allocation, when is it suppose to happen? during the call? when is the class supposed to be created ?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to set this up in the static constructor, which is guaranteed to be called exactly once?

Comment: You have to dissect the entire code: check for null, create a new instance, assign that instance to a variable. And then there are the memory and processor problems Jon was referring to in his comments. @Gilad

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well that's what the question is specifically asking.  If you personally don't feel that it's necessary to actually answer the question, and would rather just not try to answer it at all, then that's fine, don't post an answer.  But if you *are* going to post an answer, then yes, it is necessary to actually answer the question.

Comment: @theMayer It's even easier than that; you merely need to use the field's initializer to initialize the value, but Jon's article covers that and numerous other options.

Comment: @Gilad Two things are being talked about here. The answer is saying time passes between the `if (instance==null)` line and the `instance = new Singleton();`, multiple threads if they called the function at the same time could both check that `instance==null` and both see `true`, then both start creating a new instance. The thing talking about in the comments is the fact that the variable `instance` could be updated by a thread to have a value but due to caching and in the memory model and code reordering it is possible that another thread could still see null. A `lock` solves both problems.

Comment: I think it's fine for this answer to only mention one aspect - but I think it should hint that there's a lot more to it than that. Otherwise one might read this answer and think that that's all you need to protect against.

Comment: @Servy Okay, got that. I hope the update fixed that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What is that saying that the quoted section above doesn't, which is that the value *isn't* guaranteed to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please explain why...

Because it allows the JVM implementors to provide you with a JVM that gets the best possible performance on a variety of different computer architectures.

Enabling efficient and reliable communication and memory sharing between threads running on different processors of a multi-processor computer is a challenging problem for computer system designers.  There are several different approaches, and in some of them, when a thread running on one processor updates a shared variable, a thread running on a different processor may *never* see the update unless both processors take special steps to ensure that the new value is shared.

Those "special steps" can be costly.  The design of the Java programming language gives JVM developers the opportunity to take special steps when they are needed, but it does not force them to take those steps when they are not needed.

Unfortunately, the JVM can't always know what variables are being shared and when they are being shared.  So some of the responsibility is placed on you.  Google for "Java Memory Model" to find out exactly what the Java programmer's responsibilites are.